# Casting Template Function Pointers to Common Type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, templates, messaging

I'm writing a messaging system and I have a templated class right now that handles the registering and unregistering of message handlers with the messaging system. The function * that's passed into the register function is templated and I need a way to cast that to some sort of common value I can add to a look up table of some sorts so I can unregister it. When/if I cast it, I don't need to ever call that function *, I just want a consistent pointer value for lookup.
Here's what I have so far that doesn't exactly work.

```
template <typename CLASSTYPE>
class MessageRegister
{
public:
  template <typename MESSAGETYPE>
  void RegisterMessageHandler(void(CLASSTYPE::*function)(MESSAGETYPE*), std::string messageTypeName)
  {
    if (!MessageHandlerRegistered(&function, messageTypeName))
    {
      MessageHandler<CLASSTYPE, MESSAGETYPE>* messageHandler = new MessageHandler<CLASSTYPE, MESSAGETYPE>((CLASSTYPE *)this, function);
      RegisterMessageHandlerMessage registerMessage(messageHandler, Core::GetInstance().GetMessageType(messageTypeName));
      Core::GetInstance().BroadcastMessage(&registerMessage);
      AddMessageHandler(&function, messageTypeName, messageHandler);
    }
  }
private:
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<void*, IHandler*>> messageHandlers;

  void AddMessageHandler(void* function, std::string messageType, IHandler* messageHandler)
  {
    messageHandlers[messageType][function] = messageHandler;
  }

  bool MessageHandlerRegistered(void* function, std::string messageType)
  {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unordered_map<void*, IHandler*>>::iterator messageTypeIterator = messageHandlers.find(messageType);
    if (messageTypeIterator == messageHandlers.end())
      return false;

    std::unordered_map<void*, IHandler*>::iterator functionInterator = messageTypeIterator->second.find(function);
    if (functionInterator == messageTypeIterator->second.end())
      return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

The biggest problem here is that taking the address of a function * and using that as a void * is not consistent what so ever so when I go to unregister the message handler and pass in the same function *, that address isn't the same as what's in the lookup table and it can't remove it properly.

So my question is, is there a common function * type I can cast all of these templated function pointers to to use as a key in my lookup table? and if not, can anyone think of other options for storing my message handlers? The two keys for a message handler are the function * and the messageTypeName as I don't ever seen a case where a function will be registered to a message type more then once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution that works, I'm able to cast the function * to a void * by doing the following.

```
void* ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*&>(function);
```

and passing that in and using that void * as a key and it seems consistant.
If anyone has a better or different solution, I'd love to hear it but for now, it's working as intended.

Thanks!